# How do I know what changed in my Observable class?

Tags: java, android, observable, observer-pattern, observers

So I'm using the `Observer` pattern in my app in order to get notified of changes in another class without having to look for them.

I have a `Singleton` class which extends `Observable`. Inside this class I have **two** `CountDownTimer` type variables. Eachs of these contains two methods: `onTick()` and `onFinished()`.

Let's call those Timers **A** and **B** for the sake of simplicity.

Every time `A.onTick()`, `A.onFinished()`, `B.onTick()`, `B.onFinished()` are called, I must call `notifyObservers()` to notify my `Observer` that something has changed.

Until here everything works fine. The problem is that I know something has changed, but I don't know what exactly has changed. Depending on which one notified me, I must execute some code on the `Observer` side.

How do I know which of these methods notified me?

Comment: Observer/Observable have their limitations. I'd recommend you create your own implementation

Comment: Show us the classes, please... All three of them (both `Observers`s and the `Observable`, shorten them down to the important parts, maybe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LiveData` instead of `Observable`. `LiveData` is quite useful because not only it's observable but also it binds to your activity's lifecycle so you don't have to worry about handling it yourself.

Maybe this example will help you:

```
public class MyTimerWrapper {

    public static MyTimerWrapper getInstance() {
        // Your singleton logic

        createTimers();

        return instance;
    }

    private CountDownTimer timerA;
    private CountDownTimer timerB;

    private MutableLiveData<TimerEvent> timerALiveData = new MutableLiveData<TimerEvent>();
    private MutableLiveData<TimerEvent> timerBLiveData = new MutableLiveData<TimerEvent>();

    public LiveData<TimerEvent> startTimerA() {
        timerA.start();
        return timerALiveData;
    }

    public LiveData<TimerEvent> startTimerB() {
        timerB.start();
        return timerBLiveData;
    }

    private void createTimers() {
        createTimerA();
        createTimerB();
    }

    private void createTimerA() {
        timerA = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // If you're running on another thread
                timerALiveData.postValue(TimerEvent.TICK);

                // Otherwise
                timerALiveData.setValue(TimerEvent.TICK);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // If you're running on another thread
                timerALiveData.postValue(TimerEvent.FINISH);

                // Otherwise
                timerALiveData.setValue(TimerEvent.FINISH);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTimerB() {
        // Same as createTimerA, but with timerB
    }
}

public enum TimerEvent {
    TICK,
    FINISH
}
```

Now to observe that data in your activity:

```
MyTimerWrapper timerWrapper = MyTimerWrapper.getInstance();
timerWrapper.startTimerA().observe(this, new Observer {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(TimerEvent timerEvent) {
        // Here you'll be able to see whether timerA is ticking or finished
    }
})
```

Comment: And how would you unregister the observer? I know that it works with lifecycle, but in my case the lifecycle wont kill the observer. So I need to kill it explicitly.

I could call `removeObservers();` but I don't know If that would also remove the observer from the Timer B for example.

Comment: That's strange because when you observe a `LiveData` you provide the lifecycle owner (the activity or fragment) - see `observe(this, ...)` where `this` stands for the lifecycle owner. When you do that, your `LiveData` will be observed by your activity/fragment whilst it's in foreground but when your lifecycle owner is destroyed the `LiveData` will no longer be observed

Comment: Exactly. But in my case I did not destroy my activity/fragment yet. So no lifecycle event was triggered.

Anyway, I found out that `removeObservers();` do not affect different observers(I hope) - I haven't fully tested yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom `EventType` class and pass it to `Observable.notifyObservers(Object arg)`:

```
public class EventType {

    String eventType; //"onTick" or "onFinish"
    TimerType timerType;

    EventType(String eventType, TimerType timerType){

        this.eventType = eventType;
        this.timerType = timerType;
    }
}
```

`TimerType` is an enum type:

```
public enum TimerType {
    A,
    B;        
}
```

and create `TimerA` and `TimerB` classes extending `CountDownTimer`:

```
private class TimerA extends CountDownTimer {

    final EventType onTickEvent = new EventType("onTick", TimerType.A);
    final EventType onFinishEvent = new EventType("onFinish", TimerType.A);

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        notifyObservers(onTickEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        notifyObservers(onFinishEvent)
    }
}
```

The `Observer`will receive the `EventType` instance via its `update(Observable o, Object arg);` in the `arg` argument

Comment: And how would you access these types on the `update()` method in the Observer?
For example with a switch().

Comment: The TimerType is passed to the Observers through the update() method. You can then use a switch or if (arg == TimerType.A){...}

Comment: Still you wouldn't be able to tell if you we're notified by a TICK or a FINISHED

Comment: Then create an EventType class with 2 attributes: the event type and timer type. I've updated my answer